# How to get the <input> element which is under the <span> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

For the following:

```
<span class="cbChildItems" id="parent_{5D198B00-A55C-411E-9AA1-E989A768A6F3}_0">
<input id="contentpage_0_content_0_cblSubsidiaries_4" name="contentpage_0$content_0$cblSubsidiaries$4" value="{BA867562-97A8-4F24-877A-DE634A4A444A}" type="checkbox">
<label for="contentpage_0_content_0_cblSubsidiaries_4">STARCO GB Ltd</label>
</span>
```

I want to get the `<input>` element under `<span>`. So with the Id of Span I want to get the inner element.

some thing like:

```
$("span").children(). ??
```

Comment: If you want to change how ASP.NET renders the html, you can do that by overriding the `Render` method. But that will definitely make your code complex. Since you are doing this just to manipulate things with jQuery, You can use the values if they are added to `span`, IMHO it's dead easy doing it on client side.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Its better to avoid complexities. I will update my question with my final goal may be some better suggestions comes up.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you share a short sample of how you are populating this checkbox?

Comment: I have updated the question again ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#parent_{5D198B00-A55C-411E-9AA1-E989A768A6F3}_0").children("input")
```

[`.children()`](http://$(%22span%22).children()) allows filtering by selector.